# Why I can't redirect output of gcc -H

Tags: c, linux, gcc

When I execute

```
gcc -H myfile.c 2>&1 > gcc.log
```

I get the following output on the screen:

```
. /usr/include/argp.h
.. /usr/include/stdio.h
... /usr/include/features.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h
... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h
... /usr/include/libio.h
.... /usr/include/_G_config.h
..... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h
..... /usr/include/wchar.h
.... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio_lim.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sys_errlist.h
.. /usr/include/ctype.h
... /usr/include/endian.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/endian.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap-16.h
... /usr/include/xlocale.h
.. /usr/include/getopt.h
.. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed/limits.h
... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed/syslimits.h
.... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed/limits.h
..... /usr/include/limits.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix1_lim.h
....... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h
........ /usr/include/linux/limits.h
...... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix2_lim.h
.. /usr/include/errno.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h
.... /usr/include/linux/errno.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/errno.h
...... /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h
....... /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h
. /usr/include/argz.h
.. /usr/include/errno.h
.. /usr/include/string.h
... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h
. /usr/include/stdlib.h
.. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitflags.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h
... /usr/include/time.h
... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/select.h
..... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigset.h
.... /usr/include/time.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/time.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sysmacros.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
.. /usr/include/alloca.h
... /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h
.. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib-float.h
.. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdbool.h
.. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdint.h
... /usr/include/stdint.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wchar.h
.... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
Multiple include guards may be useful for:
/usr/include/limits.h
/usr/include/linux/errno.h
/usr/include/wchar.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/errno.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap-16.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/endian.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/select.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigset.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio_lim.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib-float.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sys_errlist.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/time.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitflags.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed/syslimits.h
```

When I look into gcc.log, it is empty. What is going on? Why can I not capture the output of `gcc -H`?

What does the message `Multiple include guards may be useful for:` mean?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe that's not stderr. could be some other filehandle that also writes to the terminal. try 3, 4, etc... instead of 2

Comment: The redirections are in the wrong order: `gcc -H myfile.c > gcc.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OSX (which uses `clang`), `gcc -H` *does* write to stderr. However, your shell redirects stdin after it redirects stderr because it processes `> gcc.log` before `2>&1`.

Instead, you can flip the order of the redirections:

`$ gcc -H myfile.c > gcc.log 2>&1`

This will first perform the redirection of stdin to `gcc.log` and then redirect stderr to stdin, which is now `gcc.log`.

Alternatively, you can be explicit with both:

`$ gcc -H myfile.c > gcc.log 2> gcc.log`

Comment: What about the `Multiple include guards may be useful for:` in the output. What does it mean?

Comment: @flashburn A "multiple include guard", as I know it, is a way of using `#define` and `#ifdef` to avoid including the same file multiple times, in case that has adverse behavior.

That line might mean that those files are included multiple times and they should use the inclusion guards. However, I'm not too sure on that. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768477/multiple-include-guards-may-be-useful-for-what-exactly) for a bit more information.

Comment: In this case though, the "Multiple include guards" concerns itself with system headers, which you can't do anything about. If you open the /usr/include/limits.h file, it likely lacks an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the redirections in the wrong order, and AFAIK, you only need to redirect standard error as there's nothing on standard output.

```
$ gcc -H myFile.c 2>gcc.log
```

Doing `2>&1` before `>gcc.log` will first redirect standard error to the console (where standard output was going), *then* redirect standard output to the file.